# Remove lines in file

Tags: text-processing

Trying to find lines that are greater than 59 but do not include any spaces.
E.g.,

```
a1e4fa338aae3e87250f4dbff518b8d72a004201395996a8474a252d25: found

a1e4fa f38aae3e8725 0f7dbff518b 3d7a004601395932a8474a252d253j5ns9k2j: Removed/skipped.
```

Trying to use grep but not finding the answer.

Comment: Can you please clarify "lines that are greater than 59"?

Comment: `egrep '^[^[:space:]]{60,}$'`

Comment: that would work but i have other lines with spaces that are above 59. Trying to make it so if they have any spaces they will not be apart of the output

Comment: That will match to the end of the line (`$`), have you really tried it?

Comment: mosvy solution works great

Answer (score 1):

Suppress any line that

- has a space in it
- is shorter than 59 chars

```
grep -Ev '[[:space:]]|^.{,58}$' file
```